# Qual a desvantagem em não utilizar um arquivos de rotas em php?

Tags: php

Em vários frameworks se faz necessário setar uma rota no sistema, como no exemplo abaixo.

`Route::get('MeuController/MinhaAction', function ($name) {
//
})`

Porém, gostaria de saber o que ocorre trabalhando da seguinte forma sem ter um arquivo de rotas definidas.

No caso, ao acessar o site, meu código iria verificar se existe o arquivo *MeuController*. Se existir, ele instancia a class *MeuController*. Depois de instanciado, verifica se existe a action *MinhaAction*, caso isso seja verdadeiro ele exibiria o conteúdo daquele determinado controller, caso não exista, informaria uma pagina de erro.

Enfim, na prática isso funciona normalmente e é bastante utilizado, mas os frameworks nao trabalham dessa forma. Isso afeta em algo? Em quais situações eu poderia enfrentar problemas no meu sistema?

Comment: Depende muito do framework, alguns podem até não funcionar sem rota, como o Laravel, outros acabam inutilizando as rotas como o LazyPHP. Na teoria a definição de rotas seria para dizer ao sistema coisa links seram reconhecidos e executados, tambem na teoria, uma rota mesmo existente mas nao definida como rota não poderia ser acessada. Mas pode variar entre framework.